# Redirect all custom pages to specialized page using htacess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have created following pages such as

```
Index_inner.php
info_inner.php
video_inner.php
comment_inner.php
```

and many more

I want to redirect

```
*_inner.php -> *.php
```

For example

```
Index_inner.php -> index.php
info_inner.php -> info.php
```

I am redirecting using following .htaccess code.

```
RewriteRule info_inner.php info.php
```

But, how to redirect all `(*_inner)` pages by using one coded sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this via a [rewriterule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and applying a regex.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.+)_inner\.php$ /$1.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles, URL is redirected. But another problem - this code consider htdocs as my web directory. It redirect as following format **(localhost:8080/news/index_inner.php -> localhost:8080/dashboard), (localhost:8080/news/info_inner.php -> localhost:8080/info.php)**. I think it is **base directory** issues. How to fix it ? Please guide me.. My website directory is **NEWS** and, it uses 8080 port.

Comment: With a redirect you should use an absolute URL. The reason it's going to the root is because of the `/$1.php`. If you changed it to `$1.php` (or `/news/$1.php`) it should do what you want. However, like I said it would be better to do it with an absolute URL (i.e. `RewriteRule ^news/(.+)_inner\.php$ http://localhost:8080/news/$1.php [R=301,L]`)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564275/1168379 for why it should be absolute. And yes they did update the standard recently, however some crawlers/browsers/clients may not handle them as you expect them to. Using an absolute URL gives a clear signal on where you want to redirect the URL to (protocol, port, etc).

Comment: It works. @Charles Thank you for your help and prompt reply.